# Exclude Java package from dependency jar

Tags: maven, jar, dependencies, maven-3

I want to use jar from third party vendor. But in this jar I have old version of Java package `org.osgi.framework` I need to find some way to exclude the package from the main project. Something like this:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
          <artifactId>com.ibm.ws.admin.client</artifactId>
          <version>8.5.0</version>
          <exclusions>
             <exclusion>org.osgi.framework</exclusion>
          </exclusions>
          <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Can you recommend some solution?

Answer (score 8):

Although a better solution would be to re-pack the dependency (without the unwanted package) with a classifier (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34686298/5606016)) and publish it on your enterprise Maven repository (or [install it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442230/how-to-manually-install-an-artifact-in-maven-2) into your local Maven cache, if it's a personal project), below is a different solution which should also suit your needs.

You could have a [multi-module](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation) Maven project, having a module with just this dependency and in it you could use the [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin) and its `filters` property as explained in its [official example](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html).

As per [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html), the `filters` element:

> Archive Filters to be used. Allows you to specify an artifact in the form of a composite identifier as used by artifactSet and a set of include/exclude file patterns for filtering which contents of the archive are added to the shaded jar

In your case, the following configuration should apply the filter:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>com.ibm:com.ibm.ws.admin.client</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org/osgi/framework/**</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The generated jar from the `package` phase should not contain that package any longer. As part of the Maven output you should see:

> [INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:2.4.3:shade (default) @ test-checksum ---
>   [INFO] Including com.ibm:com.ibm.ws.admin.client:jar:8.5.0 in the shaded jar.
>   [INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.

You can verify the content of the generated jar, the filtered package should not be there.

Then, the output of this module will have the "new"/filtered jar you were looking for. Then the consumer module would just need to have a dependency on this module and as such have the filter applied.
An example of such a multimodule project would be:

```
+ aggregator/parent project
    - filtered-dependency-module (applying the shade filter)
    - consumer-module (having dependency on the filtered module)
```

**Update**
Further note: in the module which applies the filter, you should declare the dependency as [optional](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) so that the consumer module doesn't bring it in transitively again.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.ws.admin.client</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.0</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Optional doesn't affect the module itself, only the consumer one. And the Shade plugin will keep on working (I re-tested it, just in case).

Comment: @PeterPenzov did you try the approach above? did it work out?

Comment: No, I still have the same problem even with the proposed solution.

Comment: So you configured a multimodule maven project with a module just for this dependency creating the filtered ibm library, then your module having a dependency on this one (hence no ibm dependency on it anylonger) and you still get the package?

Comment: No, this time I get compilation warning. Looks like Netbeans have to be configured not to use the package into the JVM classpath