# How to exclude certain package while running the Code Coverage in spring Boot using jacoco

Tags: junit, code-coverage, jacoco-maven-plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/package1/subpackage/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I want to ignore all class under certain package.
Im running Code coverage option given in the eclipse itself.
If anything is wrong comment down

Comment: Whether this solution helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955820/exclude-java-package-from-dependency-jar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example for `includes` and `exclude` configuration of jacoco-maven-plugin.

> All classes which has jacocodemo in it is package are included except if they have jacocodemo/strings in them.

```xml
<execution>
    <id>jacoco-report</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>report</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/jacocodemo/**/*</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/jacocodemo/strings/*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```